# Converting List[Future[Int]] to Future[List[Int]] with failed futures

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Say I have the following snippet

```
def testFailure2() = {
    val f1 = Future.failed(new Exception("ex1"))
    val f2 = Future.successful(2);
    val f3 = Future.successful((5));
    val f4 = Future.failed(new Exception("ex4"))
    val l = List(f1, f2, f3, f4)
    l
  }
```

The return type is `List[Future[Int]]`. In a normal way, I can just do Future.sequence and get `List[Future[Int]]`. But in this scenario it won't work as I have a failed Future. So I want to convert this to List[Future[Int]] by ignoring the failed Futures. How do I do that?

Second Q on similar topic I have is, I understand `filter, collect, partition, etc on a List`. In this scenario, say I wanted to `filter/partition` the `list` into two lists
- Failed Futures in one
- Successfully done Futures in another.

How do I do that?

Comment: On `Future.sequence` you'd have to pattern `match` whether `Success(_)` or `Failure(_)` on the results anyway, where you can do whatever you want to do with failed futures.

Comment: So, can Future.sequence accept a PF where I only do collect on successful futures? Because if I do a pattern match, I might end up with Future[Option[Int]] which will be more like Future(Some(1)), None, etc

Comment: @prayagupd, Future.sequence, takes iterable, how will I do case match on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to first convert all `Future[Int]`s to `Future[Option[Int]]` that always succeed (but result in `None` if the original future fails). Then you can use `Future.sequence` and then flatten the result:

```
def sequenceIgnoringFailures[A](xs: List[Future[A]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[A]] = {
  val opts = xs.map(_.map(Some(_)).fallbackTo(Future(None)))
  Future.sequence(opts).map(_.flatten)
}
```

Comment: This is a good snippet. Thanks a lot. But can I not do a PF using collect on Futures that have succeeded? I am not able to think how to and if that is possible

Comment: List's collect method would have to execute immediately, whereas you won't know if the futures succeeded until some point in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct : you should use a Future[List[X]] where X is something that differentiate between failure and success. It can be an Option, an Either, a Try, or whatever you want.

It seems like you're bothered by this, and I suppose it's because you're willing to find something like :

- Do all these futures in parallel, ignore the failed ones during the process

And you're given

- Do all these futures, wait for everything to finish, and discard based on the result

But actually, there is no special way to express "ignore the failed ones". Something has to acknowledge each future result since you're interested in it, otherwise starting it makes no sense in the first place. And this something has to wait for all futures to finish anyway. And as such, the flag for "you can now ignore me" is indeed the Option being None, the Either being Left, or the Try being Failure. There is not, afaik, a specific flag for futures for "this result being discarded", and I don't think scala would need one.

So, fear not, and go for Future[List[X]], because it actually expresses what you want ! :-)

Comment: I get the answer. Your answer also helped me get convinced that yes there is no other way apart from what you suggested. I found another similar answer that wraps in Try. I am struggling to wrap it in ``Left/Right``. Once I map the List, I get a ``Future[Int]``. but I am unable to do a case match on it to fill in ``Left/Right``. The syntax I am trying does not compile. How do I do that?

Comment: Got it finally
``val again = l.map{fut=>fut.map(x=>Right(x)).recover{case f=>Left(f)}}``

Comment: Seems perfect :)